# Java Hibernate Inheritance (could not insert, no value specified for parameter)

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, inheritance

I have a question about Hibernate. When I'm trying to make table per class hierarchy, I'm receiving error

```
Hibernate: insert into UZYTKOWNIK (eMail, dataRejestracji, numerTelefonu, nazwaFirmy, kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku, rabat, TYP_UZYTKOWNIKA, UZYTKOWNIK_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'K', ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [KabSystem.User.Firma.Klient]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:301)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.save(Unknown Source)
    at Main.createAndStorePerson(Main.java:93)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 7
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2159)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2139)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5001)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1955)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
    ... 23 more
```

. I don't know what should I do. I made hibernate mapping via xml and structure of inheritance mapped classes is abstract class < abstract class < class . This is my xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="KabSystem.User.Uzytkownik" table="UZYTKOWNIK" abstract="true">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="UZYTKOWNIK_ID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

    <discriminator column="TYP_UZYTKOWNIKA" type="string"/>
        <property name="eMail" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="dataRejestracji" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="numerTelefonu" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <!--<class name="KabSystem.User.Firma.Firma" table="FIRMA">-->
        <!--<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="FIRMA_ID">-->
            <!--<generator class="native"/>-->
        <!--</id>-->
    <!--</class>-->


    <subclass name="KabSystem.User.Firma.Firma" extends="KabSystem.User.Uzytkownik">
        <property name="nazwaFirmy" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <one-to-one name="adresSiedziby" class="KabSystem.User.Adres" cascade="save-update"/>
    </subclass>

</hibernate-mapping>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass name="KabSystem.User.Firma.Klient" extends="KabSystem.User.Firma.Firma" discriminator-value="K">
        <property name="kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku" type="java.lang.Double"/>
        <property name="rabat" type="java.lang.Double"/>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

.

I changed properties in hibernate.cfg.xml (for more SQL Query information), and after this I got :

```
Hibernate:
/* insert KabSystem.User.Firma.Klient
    */ INSERT
    INTO
        UZYTKOWNIK
        (eMail, dataRejestracji, numerTelefonu, nazwaFirmy, kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku, rabat, TYP_UZYTKOWNIKA, UZYTKOWNIK_ID)
    VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'K', ?)
```

Code for classes is bellow, from top to bottom like in inheritance hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Uzytkownik implements Serializable{


protected String numerTelefonu;
protected String eMail;

/*
Atrybut złożony w formie daty dodania klienta.
 */

protected String dataRejestracji;

    private Long id;

    public Uzytkownik() {
    }

    public Uzytkownik(String numerTelefonu, String eMail) {
        super();
        this.numerTelefonu = numerTelefonu;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        dataRejestracji = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }


    public String getNumerTelefonu() {
        return numerTelefonu;
    }

    public void setNumerTelefonu(String numerTelefonu) {
        this.numerTelefonu = numerTelefonu;
    }

    public String geteMail() {
        return eMail;
    }

    public void seteMail(String eMail) {
        this.eMail = eMail;
    }

    public String getDataRejestracji() {
        return dataRejestracji;
    }

    public void setDataRejestracji(String dataRejestracji) {
        this.dataRejestracji = dataRejestracji;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}




public class Firma extends Uzytkownik {

    private Long id;

    protected String nazwaFirmy;
    protected Adres adresSiedziby;

    public Firma() {
    }

    public Firma(String numerTelefonu, String eMail, String nazwaFirmy, Adres adresSiedziby) {
        super(numerTelefonu, eMail);
        this.nazwaFirmy = nazwaFirmy;
        this.adresSiedziby = adresSiedziby;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNazwaFirmy() {
        return nazwaFirmy;
    }

    public void setNazwaFirmy(String nazwaFirmy) {
        this.nazwaFirmy = nazwaFirmy;
    }

    public Adres getAdresSiedziby() {
        return adresSiedziby;
    }

    public void setAdresSiedziby(Adres adresSiedziby) {
        this.adresSiedziby = adresSiedziby;
    }
}





public class Klient extends Firma {



    /*
    Atrybut pochodny, przedstawiający aktualny rabat.
     */
    private double rabat = 0;

    /*
    Maksymalny rabat, jaki może uzyskać klient. Atrybut klasowy.
     */
    private static double maxRabat = 10;

    private double kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku;

    /*
    Lista z notatkami do klienta.
     */
    private ArrayList<String> notka = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
    Asocjacja Binarna
     */
    private ArrayList<Zamowienie> zamowienia = new ArrayList<>();


    public Klient() {
    }

    /*
        Konstruktor Klienta bez dodatkowej notatki.
         */
    public Klient(String numerTelefonu, String eMail, String nazwaFirmy, Adres adresSiedziby) {
        super(numerTelefonu, eMail, nazwaFirmy, adresSiedziby);
    }

    /*
    Przeciążony konstruktor Klienta z dodatkową notatką.
     */
    public Klient(String numerTelefonu, String eMail, String nazwaFirmy, Adres adresSiedziby, String notka) {
        super(numerTelefonu, eMail, nazwaFirmy, adresSiedziby);
        this.notka.add(notka);
    }

    /*
    Metoda pozwalająca na aktualizację rabatu klienta w zależności od jego sumy wydatków w roku ubiegłym.
    (tutaj mamy atrybut pochodny rabat)
     */
    public double aktualizujRabat(double sumaWydatkowZpoprzedniegoRoku){
        double nowyRabat = sumaWydatkowZpoprzedniegoRoku/200000;
        if(nowyRabat/200000 >maxRabat){
            rabat = maxRabat;
            return rabat;
        }else{
            rabat = nowyRabat;
            return rabat;
        }
    }

    public double getRabat() {
        return rabat;
    }

    public static double getMaxRabat() {
        return maxRabat;
    }

    public static void setMaxRabat(double maxRabat) {
        Klient.maxRabat = maxRabat;
    }

    public void dodajNotke(String nowaNotka){
        this.notka.add(nowaNotka);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNotka() {
        return notka;
    }

    public void setKwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku(double kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku){
        this.kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku = kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku;
        aktualizujRabat(kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku);
    }

    public double getKwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku(){
        return kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku;
    }

    public void dodajZamowienie(Zamowienie zamowienie) throws Exception {
        if(!zamowienia.equals(zamowienie)){
            zamowienia.add(zamowienie);
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Zamówienie już jest w liście zamówień tego klienta");
        }
    }


    public void setRabat(double rabat) {
        this.rabat = rabat;
    }

    /*
        Przesonięcie metody toString.
         */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for(String notatka : notka){
            sb.append("*"+notatka+"\n");
        }
        return  "Id:" +getId() + "\n" +
                "Nazwa Firmy:" + nazwaFirmy + '\n' +
                "Adres Siedziby:" +"\n"+ adresSiedziby + '\n' +
                "Numer Telefonu:" + numerTelefonu + '\n' +
                "Adres e-mail:" + eMail + '\n' +
                "Data Rejestracji:" + dataRejestracji + '\n' +
                "Kwota wydana w zeszym roku:"+ kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku+ "zł\n" +
                "Rabat:" + rabat +"%\n"+
                "Notki:\n" + sb.toString() ;
    }

    public Klient(String numerTelefonu, String eMail, String nazwaFirmy, Adres adresSiedziby, Long id, double kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku) {
        super(numerTelefonu, eMail, nazwaFirmy, adresSiedziby);
        this.kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku = kwotaZakupowZzeszlegoRoku;
    }

    public static void pokazEkstensje() throws Exception{
        pokazEkstensje(Klient.class);
    }
}
```

Here is my DB structure: [structure of MySQL DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8So8C.png)
Everything looks like it should be okay and should work fine... but it hasn't...

I have one clue for this problem. No value specified for parameter 7 pointing on discriminator-value, and I changed few times range of inheritances from 3 lvls to 1 lvl, and from way of inheritance: 
abstract class < class 
to 
class < class,

every time I have issue in that same context...

Please help, I'm fighting with that from 2 days...

Comment: Please show your code in your question - I for one am not visiting 6 pastebin links and an imgur image...

Comment: The error says your not setting parameter number 7.

Comment: @KarlNicholas yep, I know. That's discriminator-value... but I set it in xml.

Comment: Well, if you're inserting I don't think you need to specify the discriminator column. A basic example (with annotations) https://wordpress.com/read/feeds/44206180/posts/958867622